# How initialize a vector of objects in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector

Given the following class:

```
class MyRecord {
public:
    int a;
    int b;
    MyRecord() : MyRecord(8, 9) {};
    MyRecord(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {};
};
```

What's the easiest way to initialize my vector:
`std::vector<MyRecord> myVector` with some data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demonstrated via example:

```
MyRecord exampleRecord(3,4);
std::vector<MyRecord> myVector = {{1,2}, {}, exampleRecord};
```

For verification, the following code

```
for (MyRecord &record : myVector) {
    std::cout << "a:" << record.a << " b:" << record.b << std::endl;
}
```

will output:

```
a:1 b:2
a:8 b:9
a:3 b:4
```